# Detect seeking video event HMTL5 (mainly on iOs4)

Tags: javascript, ios4, html5-video, dom-events

I need to detect `seeking` event, because on iOs4 there's `seeked` but no seeking event.
I would not like to detect the device but the functionality.

I could make an awful `addEvent`/`fireEvent`, but I'm looking for something as sexy as `'seeking' in myElement`.

Any solution?

Comment: are you sure there s no 'seeking' event on iOs4?! I don't have a device here for testing it myself, but to make sure 'seeking' doesn't work check this page and seek in the video: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: No, there's no dispatch of seeking. On iOs5 there's no problem, but on the 4, you just have "seeked".

Also, my idea to dispatch an events is a bad idea because if I dispatch it, it will be necessarily catched.

Comment: uh. that's bad, but in this case you cannot "really" fix it. guess you have to hope for an update?!    you could try to listen to the timeupdate event to save currentVideoTime and unix timestamp, and compare them on next timeupdate event to trigger, if videotime changes faster than realtime (<- than video is seeking)). but i have no idea how the performance will change and still it would be a very ugly solution

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastUnixTimeStamp;
var lastCurrentVideoTime;

videoplayer.addEvent('timeupdate',function(){

    if( !lastUnixTimeStamp && !lastCurrentVideoTime ){  //not defined at first timeupdate event
         lastUnixTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
         lastCurrentVideoTime = videoplayer.currentTime;
         return;
    }

    var videoTimeOffset = videoplayer.currentTime - lastCurrentVideoTime;  //how many milliseconds was video running
    var realTimeOffset = new Date().getTime() - lastUnixTimeStamp;  //how many milliseconds were real time running

    //guess the numbers are not accurate, so if the difference between both is f.e. < 100ms, video runs normally 
   if( (videoTimeOffset - realTimeOffset) > 100 ){
       //do your seeking magic
   }

    lastUnixTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    lastCurrentVideoTime = videoplayer.currentTime;


})
```

as mentioned in the comment above, might be not the best solutions but should do it. good luck

Comment: You give me another idea, I change the durationTime of the video, that trigger seeking/seeked event.

The problem was that user need to activate first the video before change the duration (ipad limitation to not auto-launch video).

Answer (score 0):

This solution will only work if you are seeking forward. If you want it to work in seeking backward to, you have to verify if the videoTimeOffset is negative :

```
var lastUnixTimeStamp;
var lastCurrentVideoTime;

videoplayer.addEvent('timeupdate',function(){

if( !lastUnixTimeStamp && !lastCurrentVideoTime ){  //not defined at first timeupdate event
     lastUnixTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
     lastCurrentVideoTime = videoplayer.currentTime;
     return;
}

var videoTimeOffset = videoplayer.currentTime - lastCurrentVideoTime;  //how many milliseconds was video running
var realTimeOffset = new Date().getTime() - lastUnixTimeStamp;  //how many milliseconds were real time running

//guess the numbers are not accurate, so if the difference between both is f.e. < 100ms, video runs normally 
if( (videoTimeOffset - realTimeOffset) > 100 || (videoTimeOffset < 0 )){
   //do your seeking magic
}

lastUnixTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
lastCurrentVideoTime = videoplayer.currentTime;


})
```